# leveling system (add level to someone)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a level system in my bot, but as of now I don't have a command which adds a level to a given user.

I tried to create one, but it's not working in the current state.

The code I am using:

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="addlevel", description="Ajoutée un ou plusieur level a un membre.")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addlvl(interaction: discord.Interaction, nombre:int, author: discord.User):
    async with bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute("SELECT xp FROM levels WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?", (author.id, interaction.guild.id,))
        xp = await cursor.fetchone()
        await cursor.execute("SELECT level FROM levels WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?", (author.id, interaction.guild.id,))
        level = await cursor.fetchone()
        if not xp or not level:
            await cursor.execute("INSERT INTO levels (level, xp, user, guild) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (0, 0, author.id, interaction.guild.id,))
        level += nombre
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"le membre {author.mention} a été augmentée de {nombre} level", ephemeral=True)
```

While using the code above, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 828, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "f:\tout les dossier\project\les mien\L'asile Bot\Bot.py", line 187, in addlvl
    level += nombre
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\tamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\tamer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'addlevel' raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I've tried everything I can think of to create a new variable without using a Discord command, but nothing works.

Comment: A `NoneType` error basically means that the given user does not exist in your database.

Answer (score 0):

So I can see that if either xp or level are `None` then you are inserting some default data into the database, but after that you have `level += nombre` and this will cause a `TypeError` if level is None. The best fix here would be inside the `if` statement add `level = 0` so you reset the level variable to a default of 0 if it didn't exist in the database.

Additionally, as a note after inserting or altering data in a table you will want to use `cursor.commit()` to commit the changes you have made.

So your code becomes:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="addlevel", description="Ajoutée un ou plusieur level a un membre.")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addlvl(interaction: discord.Interaction, nombre:int, author: discord.User):
    async with bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute("SELECT xp FROM levels WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?", (author.id, interaction.guild.id,))
        xp = await cursor.fetchone()
        await cursor.execute("SELECT level FROM levels WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?", (author.id, interaction.guild.id,))
        level = await cursor.fetchone()
        if not xp or not level:
            await cursor.execute("INSERT INTO levels (level, xp, user, guild) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (0, 0, author.id, interaction.guild.id,))
            level = 0
        level += nombre
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"le membre {author.mention} a été augmentée de {nombre} level", ephemeral=True)
```

Hope this helps